# Why can't Cygwin CVS read the CVS password file in a Ruby/Perl script?

Tags: ruby, perl, cygwin, cvs

On the Windows command line and cygwin bash I can execute the following without problems:

```
cvs login
cvs -Q log -N -rVersion_01_00
```

A ruby script in the same directory contains the following:

```
`cvs login`;
`cvs -Q log -N -rVersion_01_00`;
```

When I execute the ruby script on the Windows command line I get the following error:

```
cvs log: warning: failed to open /cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings/za100744/.cvspass for reading: No such file or directory
```

If I run the script in a cygwin bash shell I get the same output I would as when I type in the commands manually.

I have no idea as to what is going wrong. The path generated by the Ruby script is wrong since it is a cygwin path but it works correctly directly on the command line. I use cvs that came as part of cygwin:

```
which cvs
cvs is an external : C:\cygwin\bin\cvs.exe
```

Ruby is the one-click installer version:

```
which ruby
/cygdrive/c/Ruby/bin/ruby
```

It seems like cvs under Ruby can not resolve /cygdrive/c to c: but works OK from the cmdline.

Perl gives me exactly the same problem.

```
my $str = "cvs -Q log -N -r$cvs_tag|";
open(CVS_STATUS, $str) or die "\n##ERROR##";
```

Comment: Your ruby/perl, are they from cygwin too?

Comment: Ruby and perl are non Cygwin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a [windows native compiled CVS](http://ftp.gnu.org/non-gnu/cvs/binary/stable/x86-woe/) solves the problem. It is not ideal since I have to send a cvs executable with the script for users that has cygwin CVS but its better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like either CVS can't create the file, or your path is wrong. Does the file `.cvspass` exist? If not, [this page](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/anoncvs.html) suggests you try creating an empty `.cvspass` file and then run your command. e.g. do

```
touch ~/.cvspass
```

If this doesn't help, then the problem is probably path related. There are a few possibilities; `$HOME` not set correctly, your home dir not matching what's in `\etc\passwd`, etc. See [this tutorial](http://www.joomlawebserver.com/freebsd/remote-access/03.-creating-a-cygwin-home-drive.html) for some troubleshooting steps that should help pin down the problem.

Comment: The file exists and is accessible. It seems like cvs under ruby can not resolve /cygdrive/c to `c:` but works OK from the cmdline.

Answer (score 0):

We had several problems with unix-, mixed- and windows-style paths in cygwin based perl scripts and built-in tools such as rsync. E.g. rsync can't handle wind-style paths. Use the tool "cygpath.exe" to adjust them correctly. Maybe it's the cause.

Comment: The path is internal to the CVS executable, so cygpath.exe will not help. But I am filing the info for future use.